# Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs'

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I encountered this problem (though the subject has been raise here but not answered).
I intend calling an formclosing event from an exitmenustrip_click event and i get this error
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs'."
Please i need help. below is my code

```
     Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click

    cashsalesForm_FormClosing(ExitToolStripMenuItem, e) '<-ERROR shows here

End Sub

    Private Sub cashsalesForm_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    //some codes here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to the specific issue, that second method has a parameter of type `FormClosingEventArgs` so, if you call it, you need to pass an object of that type.  You are passing an object of type `EventArgs`. The fact that the names are different is the clue that they are not the same.  The former inherits the latter, so it has all the same functionality plus some extra.  That extra functionality can't just be conjured out of thin air when you call a method that expects it.

With regards to the underlying issue, you don't call event handlers directly.  If you have a menu item that is supposed to close the form then you call the form's `Close` method in the `Click` event handler.  The form will then raise its `FormClosing` event and the second event handler will be executed.  That's how it works: event handlers are for handling events.

Comment: wow..that was so easy . how come i went this nuts without seeing the logic there . tnx alot Jmcilhinney

Comment: Wood. Trees. You know how it goes.